# C# Проблема с удалением файлов

Tags: c#, файлы, удаление

Не могу корректно реализовать удаление файлов, то есть моя программа неизвестно почему удаляет только файлы с папок, если файл на рабочем столе он его не может удалить, все файлы .exe

```
string[] AllFoundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(fn => Path.GetFileName(fn)).ToArray();
        string[] AllFoundFiles2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        int i = 0;
        private void fff()
        { 
            
            int iteration = AllFoundFiles.Length;
            Label[] label = new Label[iteration];

            Button[] button = new Button[iteration];
            for (; i < iteration; i++)
            {
                label[i] = new Label();
              
                label[i].Location = new Point(120, 60 + i * 31);

                label[i].Width = 500;
                label[i].Text = AllFoundFiles[i];
                label[i].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15);
                tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(label[i]);
                label[i].BringToFront();
                button[i] = new Button();
                button[i].BringToFront();
                button[i].Location = new Point(600, 60 + i * 31);
                button[i].Text = "Удалить";
                button[i].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
                button[i].Click += ButtonOnClick;
                tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(button[i]);
                button[i].BringToFront();
                panel2.BringToFront();
            }
        }
        private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
           File.Delete( AllFoundFiles2[i - 1] );
        }
```

Comment: Конечно не будет работаь. В ButtonOnClick i - чему будет равно? А чему должно быть равно? Хотите брать i с имени компонента - берите и имени. Само по себе "i" не может жить. Как у вас вообще что-то удаляет - для меня загадка.

Comment: Рабочий стол - имеет защиту, если ваша программа запущена из под анонимного пользователя - может не удалять. Но это не точно. Если не удаляет - покажите ошибку. Упростите программу так, что бы она работала и было понятно как она работает. В текущем виде сложно понять что может не работать и почему.